Connect MySQL Database to Power BI
I'm trying to connect MySQL database into Power BI desktop but it does not work. When I connect, I receive an message as the following details below:
' This connector requires one or more  additional components to be installed  before it can be used'
After receiving this message, I downloaded and installed MySQL Connector NET 8.0.33.1. However, it still does not work.
There is any way that I can fix it.
